# Why does my searchfield work on one table but not at another one?

Tags: sapui5

i got some wired problems..

```
<core:FragmentDefinition xmlns="sap.ui.table" xmlns:dnd="sap.ui.core.dnd" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
xmlns:m="sap.m">
<m:Dialog id="AuftragDialog" title="Aufträge">
    <!--    <m:beginButton>
        <m:Button text="Fertig" press=".onSaveAufträge"/>
    </m:beginButton> -->
    <m:endButton>
        <m:Button text="Zurück" press=".onCancelAufträge"/>
    </m:endButton>
    <m:content>
        <m:HBox renderType="Bare">
            <Table id="table1" selectionMode="MultiToggle" rows="{ path: 'Hallo>/results' }" visibleRowCount="10">
                <extension>
                    <m:OverflowToolbar>
                        <m:Title text="Alle Aufträge"/>
                        <m:ToolbarSpacer/>
                            <m:SearchField id="allOrder" liveChange="onFilterAllOrder">
                        <m:layoutData><m:OverflowToolbarLayoutData minWidth="25%" maxWidth="30%" /></m:layoutData>
                    </m:SearchField>
                    </m:OverflowToolbar>
                </extension>
                <columns>
                    <Column >
                        <m:Text text="Auftrags Nummer"/>
                        <template>
                            <m:Text text="{Hallo>Aufnr}" wrapping="false"/>
                        </template>
                    </Column>
                    <Column  filterProperty="Ktext">
                        <m:Text text="Auftrag"/>
                        <template>
                            <m:Text text="{Hallo>Ktext}" wrapping="false"/>
                        </template>
                    </Column>
                </columns>
                <dragDropConfig>
                    <dnd:DragInfo groupName="moveToTable2" sourceAggregation="rows" dragStart="onDragStart"/>
                    <dnd:DropInfo groupName="moveToTable1" drop="onDropTable1"/>
                </dragDropConfig>
            </Table>
            <m:VBox justifyContent="Center" class="sapUiTinyMarginBeginEnd">
                <m:Button class="sapUiTinyMarginBottom" icon="sap-icon://navigation-right-arrow" tooltip="Move to selected" press="moveToTable2"/>
                <m:Button icon="sap-icon://navigation-left-arrow" tooltip="Move to available" press="moveToTable1"/>
            </m:VBox>
            <Table id="table2" selectionMode="MultiToggle" rows="{/ZAUFK_VARSet}" visibleRowCount="10" noData="Bitte wählen sie Ihre Aufträge aus.">
                <extension>
                    <m:OverflowToolbar>
                        <m:Title text="Selektierte Aufträge"/>
                        <m:ToolbarSpacer/>
                            <m:SearchField id="selectedOrder" liveChange="onFilterSelectedOrder">
                        <m:layoutData><m:OverflowToolbarLayoutData minWidth="25%" maxWidth="30%" /></m:layoutData>
                    </m:SearchField>
                    </m:OverflowToolbar>
                </extension>
                <columns>
                    <Column>
                        <m:Text text="Auftrags Nummer"/>
                        <template>
                            <m:Text text="{Aufnr}" wrapping="false" />
                        </template>
                    </Column>
                    <Column filterProperty="Ktext">
                        <m:Text text="Auftrag"/>
                        <template>
                            <m:Text text="{Ktext}" wrapping="false" />
                        </template>
                    </Column>
                </columns>
                <dragDropConfig>
                    <dnd:DragInfo groupName="moveToTable1" sourceAggregation="rows" dragStart="onDragStart"/>
                    <dnd:DropInfo groupName="moveToTable2" targetAggregation="rows" dropPosition="Between" drop="onDropTable2"/>
                    <dnd:DragDropInfo sourceAggregation="rows" targetAggregation="rows" dropPosition="Between" dragStart="onDragStart" drop="onDropTable2"/>
                </dragDropConfig>
            </Table>
        </m:HBox>
    </m:content>
</m:Dialog>
```

thats my fragment.. on table1 there is a Searchfield and it works.. like it should.

on my second table on table2 this does not work..

and i dont really know why.. the one is a json model the other not.. maybe thats why?

controller

```
    onFilterAllOrder: function (oEvent) {
        var oTable = this.byId("table1");
        var searchText = oEvent.getParameters().newValue;
        var filters = [];

        if (searchText.trim() != '') {

            var filter1 = new sap.ui.model.Filter({
                path: "Ktext",
                operator: sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains,
                value1: searchText
            });
            filters = [filter1];
            var finalFilter = new sap.ui.model.Filter({
                filters: filters,
                and: false
            });
            oTable.getBinding("rows").filter(finalFilter, sap.ui.model.FilterType.Application);
        } else {
            oTable.getBinding("rows").filter([], sap.ui.model.FilterType.Application);
        }

    },

    onFilterSelectedOrder: function (oEvent) {
        var oTable = this.byId("table2");
        var searchText = oEvent.getParameters().newValue;
        var filters = [];

        if (searchText.trim() != '') {

            var filter1 = new sap.ui.model.Filter({
                path: "Ktext",
                operator: sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains,
                value1: searchText
            });
            filters = [filter1];
            var finalFilter = new sap.ui.model.Filter({
                filters: filters,
                and: false
            });

            oTable.getBinding("rows").filter(finalFilter, sap.ui.model.FilterType.Application);
        } else {
            oTable.getBinding("rows").filter([], sap.ui.model.FilterType.Application);
        }
    }
```

so maybe i dont see something? or make some mistakes? so i try everything.. but nothing work.. i mean it should be the same as the one before but somehow it dont work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the latter is a OData model, the filtering would be done against the service if you have not set the operation mode to client. In this case, a request against the backend is made and if that service does ignore `$filter`, you'll see no change.

Check the network tab and look if a request is made.

Comment: thanks buddy.. it works now.. it's like you said.. with the backend

Comment: @MoFug What exactly was the issue? The service wasn't just supporting `$filter` requests?

Comment: @Boghyon Hoffmann yes, the backend does not had a `IT_FILTER_SELECT_OPTIONS` method ( ($filter) request ) implemented. Now it works and i didnt had to change the code

also it is only when you use straight the Odata Model and bind it to the Table.. 
my `table1` use jsonmodel and thats why it works before.